# Is it possible to combine methods? (Python, defining class methods)

Tags: python, class, methods, defined

I'm currently working through a Python tutorial and after watching the lesson about creating a class and defining its methods I was wondering if it is possible to combine methods.

So instead of using:

```
class Coordinates:
    def point1(self):
        print(x)

    def point2(self):
        print(y)

    def point3(self):
        print(z)

x = 5
y = 4
z = 9

Coordinates.point1(x) / Coordinates.point2(y) / Coordinates.point3(z)
```

I could instead use this to call for either x, y or z:

```
class Coordinates:
    def point(self):
        print(x or y or z)


x = 5
y = 4
z = 9

Coordinates.point(x/y/z)
```

If I do that though I always get x's number 5 on the terminal no matter if I use x, y or z as self.

Thanks for any input :)

Comment: What are you trying to do? `x or y or z` will evaluate as `x` so long as `x` isn't `0` every time

Comment: In your second example you pass the arithmetic result of x/y/z but you don't use it. In the context of your *point()* function x, y & z refer to the global variables of the same name. As @C.Nivs asked, what are you trying/hoping to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to shorten the code so that I can use Coordinates.point(x, y or z) to call for the right coordinate depending on the letter used without having to create three seperate methods for x, y and z

Comment: What is a point ? What are Coordinates ? Generally, it is the other way round coordinates are attributes of points.

Comment: @Creyze The reason that you only get 5 in the output because you have use or condition. If your first condition is true, i.e in this case is x it wont check conditions further and print(x) everytime. Thank you for joining stackoverflow

Comment: Do you maybe mean `Coordinates.point('x')`, `Coordinates.point('y')` and `Coordinates.point('z')`?
Or in other words: `Coordinates.point(axis)`, where `axis` is a variable defining which coordinate you  are requesting.

Comment: This is just a parameterized method: `def point(self, name): return getattr(self, name)`. (Assuming `x`, `y`, and `z` are actually instance attributes and not global variables.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want separate functions for getting each of the x, y & z values.

Firstly you could consider having no functions at all by directly accessing the instance variables like this:

```
class Coordinates:
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z

C = Coordinates(10, 20, 30)

print(C.x, C.y, C.z)
```

Another option would be to use properties. For example:

```
class Coordinates:
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self._x = x
        self._y = y
        self._z = z
    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x
    @property
    def y(self):
        return self._y
    @property
    def z(self):
        return self._z

C = Coordinates(10, 20, 30)

print(C.x, C.y, C.z)
```

In this way you can exert control over what gets returned for any given value.

You could even make your class behave like a dictionary as follows:

```
class Coordinates:
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.d = {'x': x, 'y': y, 'z': z}

    def __getitem__(self, k):
        return self.d.get(k, None)


C = Coordinates(10, 20, 30)

print(C['x'], C['y'], C['z'])
```

In this last example you have just one function involved in the acquisition of a variable but even then you don't call it explicitly

Answer (score 0):

```
class Coordinates:
    def __init__(self,x,y,z):
        self.x=x
        self.y=y
        self.z=z
    def point(self,letter):
        if letter == "x" :
           print(self.x)
        elif letter == "y" :
           print(self.y)
        elif letter == "z":
           print(self.z)


cord= Coordinates(5,4,9)
cord.point('x')
```

Comment: At one point I had a smiliar approach using if and elif, which obviously didn't work out though, so thank you for clearing that part up for me as well!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood, you want to call a ***single method*** from the **Class** which should **execute conditions based on what input is specified [x or y or z]** instead of having **separate methods** for those.

If that's the case, you can read below on **how to do it**

```
class Coordinates:
    def __init__(self,x,y,z):
        self.x_value = x # Holds the value of x coordinate when initializing the class
        self.y_valye = y # Holds the value of y ...
        self.z_value = z # Holds the value of z ...

    # The match case is only available in python 3.10 + [ you can use simple if else statements instead for below versions ]
    def eval_point(self,coordinate_axis):
        match coordinate_axis:
            case "x":
                print("Eval x coordinate function here")
            case "y":
                print("Eval y coordinate function here")
            case "z":
                print("Eval z coordinate function here")



x = 5
y = 4
z = 9

eval_coordinate = Coordinates(x,y,z) # Values should be passed in order as defined in constructor
eval_coordinate.eval_point("x") # Change the string value to whatever coordinate eval you want [example x,y,z]
```

Comment: Thank you for your input and the explanation for each step. This is the first time I've heard of a match case statement, is there any benifit using it over an if elif else statement?

Comment: There is a lot of advantages that i cant explain here. The most convening one it is easier to code than if-else for each statements. And Btw , if you found my answer helpful, upvoting it or ticking will be helpful! .